# Why is the propulsive force related Coriolis term ignored in flight dynamics (rocket equation)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, aircraft, propulsion, coriolis-effect, variable-mass-systems

Consider a variable mass vehicle body $B$ with it's center of mass $B$ stationary with respect to the body fixed referenced frame $B$. We obtain the translational dynamics of the variable mass body as follows. The notation used is a combination of the old ways of [Etkin](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.4126?journalCode=jgcd) joined with the new from [Zipfel](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.102509).
[image]

Let $\frac{d^I}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^B}{dt}$ denote the time derivative of vectors calculated using the reference frames attached to an inertial $I$ and the body $B$ respectively. Let $0 < m_B(t)$ denote the mass of the system at time $0 < t$ with $\dot{m}_B < 0$. Let $\vec{F}_{B}^\text{ext}(t)$ denote the external forces acting on the system at time $t$.

Applying Newton's second law of motion and neglecting to write the differential terms, we have
$$\vec{F}_B^\text{ext}(t) = \frac{1}{dt} [m_B(t+dt)\vec{v}_B^I(t+dt) - \dot{m}_B(t) dt \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EI} - m_B(t)\vec{v}_B^I(t)] \\ = \frac{1}{dt} {\large [} (m_B + \dot{m}_B dt)(\vec{v}_B^I + \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{v}_B^I dt) - \dot{m}_B dt \frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{s}_{EI} - m_B(t)\vec{v}_B^I(t)] \\= m_B \frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{v}_B^I - \dot{m}_B \frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{s}_{EB} \\ = m_B a_B^I - \dot{m}_B \frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{s}_{EB} \\ $$
wherein we have applied used the kinematic relationship obtained from the triangle law of vector addition applied to the dislacement $\vec{s}_{EI}$ as
$$\frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EI} = \frac{d^I}{dt}(\vec{s}_{BI} + \vec{s}_{EB}) = \vec{v}_B^I + \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB},$$
where $\vec{v}_P^R := \frac{d^R}{dt}s_{PR}$ denotes velocity, that is the time derivative of the displacement vector of material particle $P$ calculated using the reference frame $R$, wherein $\vec{s}_{PR}$ denotes the displacement vector of the point $P$ with respect to any fixed reference point of the reference frame $R$ (or a material particle of the rigid body of $R$) and the points $B$ and $E$ denotes the center of mass of the system at an instant of time and the location of the exhaust of materials from the body of system $B$ and $a_P^R := \frac{d^R}{dt} \vec{v}_P^R$ denotes the acceleration of the point-mass $P$ calculated using the reference frame $R$. Further, in the equation above, the incremental decrease in the mass of the body $m_B$ given by $-\dot{m}_B \; dt$ represents the exhaust mass which has separated from the body at the time instant $t+dt$, which comes into existence after the time instant $t$. The [Coriolis theorem](https://bit.ly/38jPFsz) implies that
$\frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EI} = \frac{d^I}{dt}(\vec{s}_{BI} + \vec{s}_{EB}) = \vec{v}_B^I + \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB} = \vec{v}_B^I + \vec{v}_E^B + \vec{\omega}\times\vec{s}_{EB},$ with the more applicable equation for the derivation given as
$$\frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB} = \frac{d^B}{dt} \vec{s}_{EB} + \vec{\omega}^{BI} \times\vec{s}_{EB} = \vec{v}_E^B + \vec{\omega}^{BI} \times\vec{s}_{EB}.$$
Putting the two equations obtained together and applying the Coriolis theorem to the derivative $\frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{v}_B^I$ as well, we obtain
$$\vec{F}_B^\text{ext} = m_B \frac{d^I}{dt} \vec{v}_B^I - \dot{m}_B (\vec{v}_E^B + \vec{\omega}^{BI} \times \vec{s}_{EB}) \\ = m_B (\frac{d^B}{dt} \vec{v}_B^I + \vec{\omega}^{BI}\times\vec{v}_B^I) - \dot{m}_B \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB}.$$
Let us denote the representation of a vector $\vec{a}$ in a coordinate system attached to the reference frame $R$ by $[a]^R$. Let us denote $\vec{v}_B := [\vec{v}_B^I]^B := [u \; v \; w]^T$, $\vec{\omega} := [\vec{\omega}^{BI}]^B := [p \; q\; r]^T$, $\vec{v}_\text{rel} := [\vec{v}_E^B]^B$ and $[\vec{F}^\text{ext}_B]^B := [F_x \; F_y \; F_z]^T$. In the body coordinate system we can then represent the translational equations of motion as $$[\vec{F}^\text{ext}_B]^B = m_B (\dot{\vec{v}}_B + \vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_B) - \dot{m}_B (\vec{v}_\text{rel} + \vec{\omega} \times [\vec{s}_{EB}]), \; \vec{v}_\text{rel} := [\vec{v}_E^B]^B,$$ where we recall that $\dot{m}_B < 0$ denotes the negative of the mass flow rate (the usual convention is to assume a positive value of mass flow rate, so that, for instance in a rocket, $\dot{m}_B < 0$ means a positive mass flow rate). On distinguishing the force due to the atmospheric and exhaust surface pressures ($0 < P_a$ and $0 < P_e$ respectively) on the exhaust mass from the other (usual) external forces, the expression $[\vec{F}_B^\text{ext}]^B$ in the equation above is replaced with $[\vec{F}_B^\text{ext}]^B - (P_e - P_a)\frac{\vec{v}_\text{rel}}{|\vec{v}_\text{rel}|}$ where these forces are expressed explicitly. In most of the literature on the rocket equation, the force due to pressure is usually not stated explicitly in the prior expression and a good reference for this modeling detail is the book by [Wiesel](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.4186?journalCode=jgcd). This effect of pressure has been neglected in most mathematical models in literature related to flight or spaceflight dynamics.

Now, we observe that in almost all books, the translational dynamics are incorrectly (due to incomplete analysis involving the two reference frames $B$ and $I$, bad notation or erroneous derivation) given as $[\vec{F}^\text{ext}_B]^B = m_B (\vec{v}_B + \vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_B) - \dot{m}_B \vec{v}_\text{rel}, \; \vec{v}_\text{rel} := [\frac{d^B}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB}]^B = [v_E^B]^B,$ rather than the correct $[\vec{F}^\text{ext}_B]^B = m_B (\vec{v}_B + \vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_B) - \dot{m}_B [\frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB}]^B \\= m_B (\vec{v}_B + \vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_B) - \dot{m}_B (\vec{v}_\text{rel} + \vec{\omega} \times [\vec{s}_{EB}]), \; \vec{v}_\text{rel} := [\vec{v}_E^B]^B.$ Notice that this approximation can obtained by neglecting the Coriolis term as $$\dot{m}_B \vec{\omega} \times \vec{s}_{EB} \approx 0,$$ where $\vec{s}_{EB}$ denotes the displacement of the location of the exhaust on the body with respect to it's center of mass. Observe that this approximation is valid if $$\|\vec{\omega}^{BI} \times \vec{s}_{EB}\| = \|\vec{\omega} \times [\vec{s}_{EB}]^B\| << \|\vec{v}_\text{rel}\| = \|\vec{v}_E^B\|,$$ which includes the case $\|\vec{\omega}^{BI}\| \approx 0$ (variable mass vehicle body which does not rotate appreciably corresponding, for instance, to the [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)).

> Why do almost all books neglect (as an oversimplification) the propulsive force related to the Coriolis term $\dot{m}_B \vec{\omega} \times \vec{s}_{EB}$? The only reference which includes this term, although only implicitly (by denoting $\vec{v}_\text{rel} := \frac{d^I}{dt}\vec{s}_{EB}$, is the book (two links provided) [Introduction to Space Dynamics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/aeronautical-quarterly/article/abs/introduction-to-space-dynamics-william-tyrrell-thomson-john-wiley-london-1961-317-pp-diagrams-87s/22C31FFF345ABEF0CC999CAFD5FBA92B) by [Thomson](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3058398?journalCode=pto) (see sectoin 7.11). Please provide any references which do in fact include this term.

Comment: Perhaps this is technically correct, but why would you ever want to go into a noninertial frame that rotates with the rocket? As you say, it introduces extra terms which are annoying to deal with.

Comment: @knzhou that is a good question. The reason that we do this in the analysis of flight dynamics is to be able to write the equations of motion in the preferred coordinate system attached to the reference frame of the rigid body of the vehicle. This enables simplicity in the modeling and simulation. In fact, the references that are cited in the post all analyze the translation and rotation dynamics of rigid bodies using this approach. Despite this, most publications (papers and books) either seem to (inaccurately) drop this term entirely or only include it implicitly (thus not emphasizing it).